# javascript for - select boxes with same name or class get same value

Tags: javascript, html, select, multiple-select

Thanks in advance.

i have a form where i schedule my shows or channels as per show time. but different shows can be in same channel. for example :

- arrow -12:00 - NETFLIX -> channel 1
- flash -1:00 - NETFLIX-> channel 1
- silicon valley - 2:00 - HBO -> channel 2
- iron fist - 3:00 -NETFLIX -> channel 2

i get the list of events and channels for that. but i wanted to assign channels to them. and i want , that if i selected a channel once.. all select box with same channel name get same value.

```html
<label> Arrow </label>
<select class="form-control NETFLIX"> 
  <option value='1'> Channel 1 </option>
  <option value='2'> Channel 2 </option>
  <option value='3'> Channel 3 </option>
</select>
<br>

<label> flash </label>
<select class="form-control NETFLIX"> 
  <option value='1'> Channel 1 </option>
  <option value='2'> Channel 2 </option>
  <option value='3'> Channel 3 </option>
</select>
<br>
<label> silicon valley </label>
<select class="form-control HBO"> 
  <option value='1'> Channel 1 </option>
  <option value='2'> Channel 2 </option>
  <option value='3'> Channel 3 </option>
</select>
<br>
<label> iron fist </label>
<select class="form-control NETFLIX"> 
  <option value='1'> Channel 1 </option>
  <option value='2'> Channel 2 </option>
  <option value='3'> Channel 3 </option>
</select>
```

Here in above code : if i select any show with class NETFLIX (suppose channel 1). then all shows with Class name NETFLIX in it sets automatically to channel1.
Need  a javascript to do that.

Comment: You at least need to try to write the code yourself and then ask for help when something specific isn't working.,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I am actually confused.. because we cant use getElementByID here coz elements with same if in same for is invalid.

Comment: Each widget should have its own name attribute. How do you recognized what was selected for Flash channel?

Comment: @MaxZoom i can keep the name attributes same as channel name but still its a variable. i get a list of 100d's of channels together